# android how to setOnClickListener for fragment button

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, fragment

I have an activity and a fragment.  The fragment has a button on it.

I load the fragment:

```
fragment = new FragmentPIN(this);                   
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content,fragment);         
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

then try to set the listener

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {

        Button cmdOK_PIN = (Button)activity.findViewById(R.id.cmdOK_PIN);
        cmdOK_PIN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                       
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }

        });

    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I always get a null pointer exception on the setOnClickListener call.  The fragment transaction is committed before I attempt to set the listener.  Or I think it is.  Should I be using another override to do this?

Comment: Err, you have a button in your activity, then you want to set the onclicklistener from the fragment? Is the button defined in the layout file of the activity? Are you sure the activity has called setContentView before you use the button?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try changing where you set the listener to the `onActivityCreated` instead of `onAttach`.  According to the Android [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated%28android.os.Bundle%29):

> onActivityCreated is called when the fragment's activity has been created and this fragment's view hierarchy instantiated.

When you call `onAttach` that's before the Activity has setup its view

Answer (score 1):

Hi im new to android and was getting that nullpointer exception when I added some buttons dynamically. Fragment also has a method onViewCreated you can override.
Guessing from its name you can be sure the view is there :)

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }
```